# Protocols and standards that take advantage of the huge IPv6 address space

Tags: networking, protocols, standards, ipv6

Unsure if this is the correct place for this kind of question (Server Fault is for administrators) but I'm looking for examples of (networking) protocols and standards that leverage the huge IPv6 address space towards some specific benefits.

Reason is I'm writing a paper about something that does this and I'm searching for stuff to compare it to, but I'm coming up empty even though I'm sure some have to do so.

Comment: PS: your name looks Dutch ;)  Feel free to contact me directly if you need help with your paper.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. For context, the paper describes a way to derive multicast addresses in a pub/sub system given an IPv6 publisher address and the component one is interested in. This is only realistic for a 128-bit address since IPv4 would quickly inhibit the available options. I've even got 4 bytes left in my derived addresses without trying, which allow other information to be transmitted! The idea is not really new, but I had a hard time coming up with examples, so thanks.

Comment: I assume you know about https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3956

Comment: Instead of component, I meant "type of event", apologies.

I didn't actually, thanks, I'll be sure to read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not completely on topic here, but I'm going to answer it anyway because it might help software developers to learn what possibilities there are when developing for IPv6.

---

Because most protocols and applications still want to be compatible with IPv4 there aren't that many protocols that use this wonderful feature of IPv6. Most of the ones that do are IPv6-only by nature.

The first one is of course [IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) often abbreviated to SLAAC. Having so many addresses available makes self-assignment of addresses so much easier.

Building on that is [SEcure Neighbor Discovery](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3971) (SEND) with [Cryptographically Generated Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3972) (CGA) which uses public key cryptography and derives the last 64 bits of the IPv6 address from the fingerprint of that public key. Because the node can create a signature with the private key that matches the public key it can prove that it is the legitimate holder of that IPv6 address. Unfortunately there are no implementations for the most common operating systems so this feature is largely unused.

And another one is the [IPv6 Battleships](https://github.com/pieter/ipv6-battleships) game. It uses IPv6 addresses to encode the coordinates in the game and by sending a ping the opponent can determine of there is a ship at a certain location (address) or not. The game was written in a competition on [World IPv6 Day](http://www.internetsociety.org/ipv6/archive-2011-world-ipv6-day) at the IPv6 event in The Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

It has significant advantages for large Cloud deployments. For instance, Faceebook has reported 90% of its internal traffic is IPv6 (https://t.co/PPHBkUPTdt) because this way is similar to private IPv4 but serves better to v6 native customers (in the same report they claim v6 mobiles surf 30%-40% quicker than v4 ones).  Also Openstack has finally added almost-full v6 support for Juno version.

Additionally, the IoT field (when it is really IoT, I mean IP devices) is an excellent field of application. Normally, devices will use either IPv6 (when powerful enough) or 6LowPAN (an reduced IPv6 for sensor networks and supported well in OS like TinyOS, ContikiOS, mbedOS, etc).

It might be also useful for WebRTC-like applications as long as IPv6 peers would normally connect better (firewalls vs NATs seem to behave or be more easily configured).

However, with the massive deployment that has started in 2015 (in USA 17% of all traffic to Google is v6, Germany traffic to Google is 14%, all Internet traffic to Google is 7% IPv6 today) any Internet product of service has to migrate or will lose competitiveness soon.